# Spring JPA - where does the repository magically appear from?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, autowired

I have been trying to write a Rest controller with a GET and POST method with a JPA layer talking to a MySQL db behind it. I am trying to follow this example -

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/

As shown on this link, I added a constructor to my RestController class - something like -

```
@Autowired
    BookmarkRestController(BookmarkRepository bookmarkRepository,
                           AccountRepository accountRepository) {
        this.bookmarkRepository = bookmarkRepository;
        this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
    }
```

But I get errors saying that I do not have a bean implementing the repository implementation. How do I see this repository magically appear into my RestController?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like your interfaces for the repositories aren't where they get found by the component scanning.

Put your interfaces in the package or a subpackage of your spring boot application.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an interface for your `BookmarkRepository` and `AccountRepository`. When you define an interface Spring data `JPA` internally defines its implementation.

```
@Repository
public interface BookmarkRepository extends JpaRepository<Bookmark, Long>{

}
```

PS: IF you have defined an interface and still your code is not working that could be because your repositories are not findable by the spring container or that you dont have the required jars for `JPA`

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have the following JPA related dependencies in my pom.xml - spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and mysql-connector-java - which are quite like in the tutorial. Should I add anything?

Comment: thats pretty much it. You dont need to add anything else.